# Visual Studio: List a project's files sorted by 'Build Action'

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Working against VS2010 in C#:

Is it possible to find files where VS's property is set to 'None' without clicking each individual file from within VS?

thx

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio? Which language? Different language services use different project file formats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unload the project and edit it.  Files will be in ItemGroups under the tag

```
<None Include="File"/>
```

In VS2010, at least for C# and VB.net, all project files are just XML documents you can search through or parse programmatically.